# How To Delay Invoke-WebRequest Until Task is Complete or Make Invoke-WebRequest Actively Update

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I'm trying to write a Web-Request to speedtest.net to run an internet speed test and return the results, but since the speed test takes time and I'm not getting the results in .content, I suspect that the speed test process is not updating the request after it's completed. It could also be that
I'm not understanding how to pull the data. I just learned about invoke-webrequest yesterday so it's likely that I just don't understand how to use it yet. Also, the speedtest.exe is blocked through our network, otherwise I would have used that.

My script is as follows:

```
$URL = "www.speedtest.net/"
$site = Invoke-WebRequest $URL -UseBasicParsing
$Testpath = ($site.Links | Where-Object onclick -icontains "window.ookla.globals.shouldstartonload = true;").href
$site = Invoke-WebRequest "$url$testpath" -SessionVariable TestSession -UseBasicParsing
```

As far as pulling the data, I'm trying to use this which pulls nothing. I got the class name from speedtest.net with Chrome inspect element. I've also tried using $site.split() and using select-string

```
$site.content | where-object class -icontains "result-data-large number result-data-value download-speed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figure out how to do this?

I was able to complete with the cli, but I don't want to use an exe either.

```
######### Absolute monitoring values ##########
$maxpacketloss = 2 #how much % packetloss until we alert.
$MinimumDownloadSpeed = 100 #What is the minimum expected download speed in Mbit/ps
$MinimumUploadSpeed = 2 #What is the minimum expected upload speed in Mbit/ps
######### End absolute monitoring values ######

# Replace the Download URL to where you've uploaded the ZIP file yourself. We will only download this file once.
# Latest version can be found at: https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli
$DownloadURL = "https://install.speedtest.net/app/cli/ookla-speedtest-1.2.0-win64.zip"
$DownloadLocation = "$($Env:ProgramData)\SpeedtestCLI"
try {
$TestDownloadLocation = Test-Path $DownloadLocation
    if (!$TestDownloadLocation) {
        New-Item $DownloadLocation -ItemType Directory -force
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $DownloadURL -OutFile "$($DownloadLocation)\speedtest.zip"
        Expand-Archive "$($DownloadLocation)\speedtest.zip" -DestinationPath $DownloadLocation -Force
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Output -InputObject "The download and extraction of SpeedtestCLI failed. Error: $($\_.Exception.Message)"
exit 1
}
$PreviousResults = if (test-path "$($DownloadLocation)\LastResults.txt") { get-content "$($DownloadLocation)\LastResults.txt" | ConvertFrom-Json }
$SpeedtestResults = & "$($DownloadLocation)\speedtest.exe" --format=json --accept-license --accept-gdpr
$SpeedtestResults | Out-File "$($DownloadLocation)\LastResults.txt" -Force
$SpeedtestResults = $SpeedtestResults | ConvertFrom-Json

# Creating object
[PSCustomObject]$SpeedtestObj = @{
    downloadspeed = [math]::Round($SpeedtestResults.download.bandwidth / 125000, 2)
    uploadspeed = [math]::Round($SpeedtestResults.upload.bandwidth / 125000, 2)
    packetloss = [math]::Round($SpeedtestResults.packetLoss)
    isp           = $SpeedtestResults.isp
    ExternalIP    = $SpeedtestResults.interface.externalIp
    InternalIP    = $SpeedtestResults.interface.internalIp
    UsedServer    = $SpeedtestResults.server.host
    ResultsURL    = $SpeedtestResults.result.url
    Jitter        = [math]::Round($SpeedtestResults.ping.jitter)
    Latency = [math]::Round($SpeedtestResults.ping.latency)
}
$SpeedtestHealth = @()
# Comparing against previous result. Alerting is download or upload differs more than 20%.
if ($PreviousResults) {
    if ($PreviousResults.download.bandwidth / $SpeedtestResults.download.bandwidth * 100 -le 80) { $SpeedtestHealth += "Download speed difference is more than 20%" }
    if ($PreviousResults.upload.bandwidth / $SpeedtestResults.upload.bandwidth * 100 -le 80) { $SpeedtestHealth += "Upload speed difference is more than 20%" }
}

# Comparing against preset variables.
if ($SpeedtestObj.downloadspeed -lt $MinimumDownloadSpeed) { $SpeedtestHealth += "Download speed is lower than $MinimumDownloadSpeed Mbit/ps" }
if ($SpeedtestObj.uploadspeed -lt $MinimumUploadSpeed) { $SpeedtestHealth += "Upload speed is lower than $MinimumUploadSpeed Mbit/ps" }
if ($SpeedtestObj.packetloss -gt $MaxPacketLoss) { $SpeedtestHealth += "Packetloss is higher than $maxpacketloss%" }

if (!$SpeedtestHealth) {
$SpeedtestHealth = "Healthy - ISP: $($speedtestObj.isp) Download Speed: $($SpeedtestObj.downloadspeed) Upload Speed: $($speedtestObj.uploadspeed) Jitter: $($speedtestObj.jitter) Lattency:Lattency: $($speedtestObj.Latency) PacketLoss: $($speedtestObj.packetLoss)"
}

Write-Output -InputObject $SpeedtestObj
```